# Given that $n=\prod^r_{i=1}p_i^{k_i}$, find $|\{x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}: x^a\}|$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

Given that $$n=\prod^r_{i=1}p_i^{k_i}$$

where $k_i\in \mathbb Z_+$ and $p_i$ is prime $\forall i\in\mathbb Z_+<r$, find $$|\{x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}: x^a\}|$$

(Note: This is a proof verification question. See my proof below. Feel free to comment on it, or provide your own proof if you want.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a useful lemma: $ad\equiv bd\pmod{dc}\Rightarrow a\equiv b\pmod c$. The proof goes as follows: Let $ad=ecd+f$ and $bd=gcd+f$. We note $f=ad-ecd\Rightarrow f=hd$ for an integer $h$. Dividing $d$ from both equations, we have $a=ec+h$ and $b=gc+h$. So, $a\equiv h\equiv b\pmod c$

$b\in\{x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}: x^a\}$ iff there exists $x$ such that $x^a\equiv b\pmod n$. By Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can split $x^a\equiv b\pmod n$ into $x^a\equiv b\pmod {p_1^{k_1}}$, $x^a\equiv b\pmod {p_2^{k_2}}$, $x^a\equiv b\pmod {p_3^{k_3}}$, e.t.c.

Consider the equation $x^a\equiv b\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ where $0\leq b<p_i^{k_i}$, and suppose $p_i\neq2$ and $p_i\not\mid b$. Then there exists a primitive root $g$ modulo $p_i^{k_i}$. Suppose $x\equiv g^k\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ and $b\equiv g^m\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$. The equation becomes $g^{ka}\equiv g^m\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$. As the multiplicative order of $g$ is $\varphi\left(p_i^{k_i}\right)=p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)$ we need $ka\equiv m\pmod{p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)}$. Let $a_i=\gcd(a,p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1))$. We note that $\gcd(m,p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1))=\gcd(ka,p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1))=ca_i$ for some integer $c$, hence $\gcd(m,p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1))=ca_i$. This implies $a_i|m$.

Now let $a=a_ib_i$, $m=m_ia_i$, and $p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)=a_iq_i$, then $ka_ib_i\equiv m_ia_i\pmod{a_iq_i}\Rightarrow kb_i\equiv m_i\pmod{q_i}$. By definition $b_i$ and $q_i$ are coprime, hence by Beztout's Theorem there exists an inverse of $b_i$, and we can write $k\equiv m_ib^{-1}\pmod{q_i}$. Hence  $x^a\equiv b\pmod{p_i},p_i\not\mid b$  has a solution iff $b\equiv g^m\pmod{p_i}$ where $g$ is a primitive root and $\gcd(a,p_i-1)|k$. There are $\frac{p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)}{\gcd\left(a,p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)\right)}$ possible values of $k$ mod $p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)$ and each one corresponds to a different value of $b\pmod{p_i}$. Hence we have $\frac{p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)}{\gcd\left(a,p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)\right)}$ possible values of $b\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$.

When $k_i<3$ and $p_i=2$ and $2\not\mid b$, there exists a primitive root $g$. We can use the argument above to conclude there are $\frac{p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)}{\gcd\left(a,p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)\right)}$ possible values of $b$.

Now suppose $p_i=2$, $a_i\neq2$, $k_i\geq3$ and $2\not\mid b$. By Hensel's lifting lemma, for each solution to $y^a\equiv b\pmod{p_i}$ where $0\leq b<p_i$, there exists $x\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ such that $x\equiv y\pmod{p_i}$ and $x^a\equiv b\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$, provided that $\frac d{dx}[x^a-b]=ax^a\not\equiv0\pmod{p_i}$. The above requirements prevent $ax^a\equiv0\pmod{p_i}$ so Hensel's lemma applies. Excluding the case $b\equiv 0\pmod{p_i}$ (as that means $p|b$), there are $\frac{p_i-1}{\gcd(a,p_i-1)}$ possible values of $b<p_i$ such that $y$ exists. We note that if $y^a\equiv b\pmod{p_i}$, then $y^a\equiv b+ck\pmod{p_i}$. As $0\leq k<p_i^{k_i-1}$ (we need $0\leq b<p_i^{k_i}$), so there are $\frac{p_i^{k_i}(p_i-1)}{\gcd(a,p_i-1)}=\frac{p_i^{k_i}(p_i-1)}{\gcd\left(a,p_i^{k_i}(p_i-1)\right)}$ values of $b\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ such that $b\not\mid p$ and $x$ exists.

Now suppose $a=2$, $p_i=2$, $2\not\mid b$. We cannot apply Hensel's lemma as $\frac d{dx} x^2-b=2x\equiv 0\pmod 2$. Luckily, [Gauss has shown for us that the only odd quadratic residues mod $2^k$ are of the form $8n+1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_power_modulus). Thus, there are $2^{k_i-3}$ possible values of $b\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$.

In conclusion, if $p_i\not\mid b$, then there are $\frac{p_i^{k_i}(p_i-1)}{\gcd\left(a,p_i^{k_i}(p_i-1)\right)}$ ways of selecting $b$ such that there exists an $x$ such that $x^a\equiv b\pmod{p_i}$ if $a\neq2$ or $p_i\neq2$ and $k_i<3$, and $2^{k_i-3}$ otherwise. Let us denote this function as $f(p_i,k_i,a)$.

Now suppose $p|b$. If $k_i\geq\nu_p(b)$, then $\nu_p\left(x^a\right)=a\nu_p(x)=\nu_p(b)$, so $a|\nu_p(b)$. Let $b\equiv c\cdot p^{ka}\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ where $ka<k_i$ and $0<c<p^{ka-k_i}$ (i.e. $0<b<p^{k_i}$) and $p_i\not\mid c$. We have $\nu_p\left(x^a\right)=a\nu_p(x)=ka$, hence $\nu_p(x)=k$. Let $x=y\cdot p^k$, so $x^a\equiv b\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}\Rightarrow y^ap^{ak}\equiv c\cdot p^{ka}\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}\Rightarrow y^a\equiv c\pmod{p_i^{k_i-ka}}$. There are $f(p_i,k_i-ka,a)$ possible values of $c$, and hence, $f(p_i,k_i-ka,a)$ possible of values of $b$ where $b=c\cdot p^{ka}$ for a given $k$ where $ka<k_i$. This means, when $b\equiv c\cdot p^{ka}\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ where $k=0$ to $k=\left\lceil\frac{k_i}a\right\rceil-1$, we have $\sum^{\left\lceil\frac{k_i}a\right\rceil-1}_{k=0}f(p_i,k_i-ka,a)$.

Finally, consider when $b\equiv 0\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ Obviously there is a solution to when $x^a\equiv0\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ ($x\equiv0\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ is a solution). Hence $b\equiv0\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$ is a possible value.

Thus, there are $1+\sum^{\left\lceil\frac{k_i}a\right\rceil-1}_{k=0}f(p_i,k_i-ka,a)$ possible values of $b$ given that there exists $x$ such that $x^a\equiv b\pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$.

Now there is a unique $b\pmod n$ satisfying the linear congurences $b\equiv b_1\pmod{p_1^{k_1}}$, $b\equiv b_2\pmod{p_2^{k_2}}$, $b\equiv b_3\pmod{p_3^{k_3}}$, \cdots, $b\equiv b_r\pmod{p_r^{k_r}}$ by Chinese Remainder Theorem. There are $1+\sum^{\left\lceil\frac{k_1}a\right\rceil-1}_{k=0}f(p_1,k_1-ka,a)$ ways of selecting $b_1$, $1+\sum^{\left\lceil\frac{k_2}a\right\rceil-1}_{k=0}f(p_2,k_2-ka,a)$ ways of selecting $b_2$, ... $1+\sum^{\left\lceil\frac{k_r}a\right\rceil-1}_{k=0}f(p_r,k_r-ka,a)$ ways of selecting $b_r$. This gives $\prod_{i=1}^r1+\sum^{\left\lceil\frac{k_i}a\right\rceil-1}_{k=0}f(p_i,k_i-ka,a)$ ways of selecting $b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_r$, and hence $b$.

In conclusion, the number of solutions for $b$ is

$$\prod_{i=1}^r1+\sum^{\left\lceil\frac{k_i}a\right\rceil-1}_{k=0}f(p_i,k_i-ka,a)$$

where

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{matrix}
2^{k_i-3} \text{ if }p_i=a_i=2\text{ and }k_i\geq3 \\
\frac{p_i^{k_i}(p_i-1)}{\gcd\left(a,p_i^{k_i}(p_i-1)\right)}\text{ otherwise} 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$